# screen manager inside screen manager, accesss screens from inner screen manager

Tags: python, nested, kivy

My GUI consists of a Title bar with buttons who control a screenmanager in the middle, then the actual screen manager, and a bottom bar with status updates.

Usually i controll the screens in the middle with the buttons on top. Easy. Now my problem is, that one of those screens is super complex already, and i have a problem that i have so many indentations.. So, here we go: 
**I want to have a screen manager sm2 inside another screenmanager sm1, and access screens from sm1 from within sm2**.

I tried to recreate my problem with the following syntax, i hope i did not forget anything important. I tried playing around with dynamic classes and such, but my code is linked to a lot of python code which i access with root.functions and it didnt quite work.

Kivy syntax:

```
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, 0.1
        Label:
            text: 'Title Bar with Menu'
        Button:
            text: 'Go to Screen 1'
            on_release: sm1.current = 'outerScreen1'
        Button:
            text: 'Go to Screen 2'
            on_release: sm2.current = 'outerScreen2'

    Screenmanager:
        id: sm1
        Screen:
            name: 'outerScreen1'
            BoxLayout:
                Label:
                    text: 'Testlabel'
        Screen:
            name: 'outerScreen2'
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                size_hint: 1, 0.1
                anchor_y: 'top'
                pos_hint: {'top': 1}
                Label:
                    text: 'Title Bar inside outerScreen2'
                Button:
                    text: 'Go to innerscreen Home'
                    on_release: sm2.current = 'screen2Home'
                Button:
                    text: 'Go to innerscreen Meow'
                    on_release: sm2.current = 'screen2Meow'
                Button:
                    text: 'Go to outerscreen 1, but inside screenmanager sm2'
                    on_release: sm2.current = 'outerScreen1' **#This is where the problem is**

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                size_hint: 1, 0.9
                ScreenManager:
                    id: sm2
                    Screen:
                        name: 'screen2Home'
                        Label:
                            text: 'simple test'
                    Screen:
                        name: 'screen2Meow'
                        Label:
                            text: 'I meow sometimes'
```

Comment: Does just changing `sm2` to `sm1` (in the line you have marked) do what you want?

Comment: Hey - unfortunately not. If i do this, it shows the content in the outer screen manager and i lose my inner screen elements (which are not in this example). So i have an inner menu bar which i want to have while accessing screens from the outer screen manager.

Comment: Then what do you mean by `accessing screens from the outer screen manager`?

Comment: Showing sm1.outerScreen1 inside sm2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want, but it requires an ugly hack. In order to set the current `Screen` of a `ScreenManager`, that `Screen` must be a child of the `ScreenManager`. But any `Widget` (including `Screens`) can only have one parent. So, the ugly hack is to move the `Screen` between `ScreenManagers` as needed.

Part of a modified version of your `kv` implements part of the hack:

```
ScreenManager:
    id: sm1
    Screen:
        id: outer_screen_1  # added id
        name: 'outerScreen1'
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: 'Testlabel'
    Screen:
        name: 'outerScreen2'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            anchor_y: 'top'
            pos_hint: {'top': 1}
            Label:
                text: 'Title Bar inside outerScreen2'
            Button:
                text: 'Go to innerscreen Home'
                on_release: sm2.current = 'screen2Home'
            Button:
                text: 'Go to innerscreen Meow'
                on_release: sm2.current = 'screen2Meow'
            Button:
                text: 'Go to outerscreen 1, but inside screenmanager sm2'
                on_release:
                    # use saved id to move Screen between ScreenManagers
                    sm1.remove_widget(outer_screen_1)
                    sm2.add_widget(outer_screen_1)
                    # now we can use this Screen with sm2
                    sm2.current = 'outerScreen1' #This is where the problem is
```

I have added an `id` to the `outerScreen1`. And in the problem area, the `on_release` code now moves `outerScreen1` from `sm1` to `sm2` and make it the current screen of `sm2`.

But now the code using `sm1`:

```
    Button:
        text: 'Go to Screen 1'
        on_release: sm1.current = 'outerScreen1'
```

will fail because `outerScreen1` is no longer a child of `sm1`. So, if you want to go this route, you must keep track of where `outerScreen1` is, and change its parent as needed.

This is a good time to consider whether just making another `Screen` that duplicates `outerScreen1` might be simpler.

Comment: thank you for taking your time, i just duplicated the screen. Maybe ill find some time in the future to think about it more. Thanks :)